# Get ETH and Token Balances of Wallet address

Tags: tokens, wallets, cpp-ethereum

How do I get a simple and fast balance of ETH and all Token owned/stored within a wallet address?

I have seen similar question and the closer answer was in this demo: http://wbobeirne.com/eth-balance-checker-demo/

but why it returns only a subset of tokens? and does it make sens that it seems to "scan" all smart contracts looking for "holdings?

thank you all

Comment: I have progressed on my "tests"... apologize if this is too low level, but I am a newbie in the Ethereum World....

below my steps:

1) created an account in **https://infura.io/** in order to have access to a full node (t be used as EVM)

2) installed web3.js in nodejs -> **npm install web3**

3) got ethereum balance with: **web3.eth.getBalance(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])** (connecting to the infura server)
Is it there any way to list and look on all token generating contracts? 

How site like this one https://ethplorer.io/ gets the individual token balances?

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure - I work with QuickNode.

You can use the [QuickNode Token API](https://www.quicknode.com/token-api) to get a wallet address's tokens.

- [qn_getWalletTokenBalance](https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/qn_getWalletTokenBalance_v2) - Using this RPC method on a QuickNode Ethereum endpoint, you can fetch ERC-20 token a wallet holds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this yourself, you'll have to iterate over each erc20 smart contract to get the balance for a specific address. Some APIs offer this functionality, so you don't have to do the heavy lifting.

An example is Cindercloud, which has APIs to access [balance](https://docs.cinder.cloud/get-balance) / [token balances](https://docs.cinder.cloud/get-tokens).

Comment: Thank you for this.... I am actually trying to do some testing and I was curious to do it myself..... any tip on where to start?

Comment: I have progressed on my "tests"... apologize if this is too low level, but I am a newbie in the Ethereum World....

below my steps:

1) created an account in https://infura.io/ in order to have access to a full node (t be used as EVM)